# How to open an Image in Fancy Box on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fancybox

Hi um trying to open an image on fancy box and currently the image is open in another tab . My code is this

```
<%= link_to file.title, file_path(file) %>
```

when I  place this it open in another tab

So created anchor tag and did the following

```
<a href = "file.title, file_path(file)" class="file_preview"> <%= file.title %></a>
```

and wrote a js script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.file_preview').fancybox({
    'width' : false,
    'height' : false,
    'autoDimensions' : true,
    'autoScale' : true,
    'transitionIn' : 'none',
    'transitionOut' : 'none',
    'type' : 'iframe',
    'scroll' : 'no',
    'centerOnScroll' : true
});
});
```

this did not work but when I give an address like /testadd it opened in iframe
I do not know how to proceed further

Comment: First of all: what version of fancybox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
<a id="single_image" href="file.title, file_path(file)">
    <img src="file.title, file_path(file)" alt=""/>
</a>
```

Also make sure that you are calling on document ready

```
$("a#single_image").fancybox();
```

And of course that you have included both the fancybox js and the jquery BEFORE anything else in this order. (if you call the fancybox first and the jquery after it will not work)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
```

iFrame:

```
<a href="http://www.example?iframe">This goes to iframe</a>
```

or

```
<a class="iframe" href="http://www.example">This goes to iframe</a>
```

Comment: how may I call to fancybox iframe function?

Comment: You will need to ready the "How to use", "API & Options", "Tips & Tricks" and "FAQ" in http://fancybox.net/ as it has all these things...